# Application outside document root in Apache/CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have a PHP application running in Apache on CentOS 6. The document root is pointed to a specific app folder:

```
/var/www/my-project/app
```

I'm trying to get phpMyAdmin running on the same server but I don't want to put it in the application folder.  Instead I'd like to put it here

```
/var/www/apps/phpmyadmin
```

I'm using a sub domain for the server. What's the easiest way for me to get access to phpMyAdmin? Another subdomain? sub subdomain? Re-direct a folder?

Answer (score 1):

Which is best depends on your requirements, either phpMyAdmin is the DocumentRoot of a separate subdomain or use the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive to make an application installed in a different directory available under a specific URL:

```
Alias /tools/phpMyAdmin /var/www/apps/phpmyadmin
```

will make phpMyAdmin available on the URL `<servername>/tools/phpMyAdmin`